# fabric mouse events not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I am new to using fabric and canvas in general.

This is how I am initializing canvas:

```
fabric.isTouchSupported = false;
myService.setCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {selection: false, allowTouchScrolling: false}));
```

I have tried disabling even chrome flags that might invoke touch event instead of mouse events - chrome://flags/

The mouse events are triggered right the first time my canvas loads. However, I go back to my home page and then come to my canvas page and it stops reading mouse events.

What might be the reason?

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. So my application was creating multiple canvas objects without checking if a canvas object already exists. After I controlled that, it works as expected.